# How do I grant Windows privileges to unelevated users?

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

I need to download large files. To speed transmission I'm using multiple connections per file.  To reduce disk fragmentation I'm telling windows the final size of the file after creation.  To avoid zero initialization when I write the first byte of the last connection, I'm initializing the file as garbage with SetFileValidData.  The problem is that SetFileValidData requires the SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME privilege that normally only Administrators have.  How can I enable SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME for unelevated users (administrator users that have UAC enabled)?

Comment: How would you handle it for a standard user? What did you do under Windows XP?

Comment: @IanBoyd I don't support standard users. WinXP works as Win7 with UAC disabled.

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. Granting users the `SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME` is a security vulnerability, as they could read the contents of previously deleted files. If the user does not have that permission, there is no way you can just get it. The only way a user can get it is to logon as a user that is an administrator.

Comment: Instead of allowing an admin to give an user EXACTLY the permissions you want him to have on a folder, the OS exposes a bunch of generic properties so you are never sure exactly what they do. Then there is the brilliant UAC, which basically says "this program is trying to do something that requires admin privileges". Only it does not tell you what it is. In the end, "security experts" will all joke around saying how dumb Windows users are because they are always logged in as admin, when the reality is that they end up having to do that and OS is the one to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; there is no way to give a process running with a restricted token elevated privileges.

Consider using a system service to perform the elevated task.  There are at least three possible approaches:

- Do all the work, including the download, from the service.
- Download from the application and use shared memory to provide the data to the service to write to the file.
- Have the service create and extend the file and then provide the application with a write-only handle to it.  (It has to be write-only to ensure that the application cannot be tricked into reading the potentially sensitive data that was left in the file when you bypassed zero-initialization.)

Note that in all of these cases you also need to be careful about what permissions you set on the file.

---

Alternatively, depending on the protocol, you could organize the download streams differently.  Instead of each stream fetching a big sequential chunk of the data, so that the last stream is writing to the end of the file, have each stream fetch a series of smaller interspersed chunks which you can write to the file sequentially.

(This might not be feasible if the protocol only allows each connection to fetch a sequential block of data, because of the additional overhead of establishing a new connection for each chunk.)

Comment: Why is SE_MANAGE_VOLUME_NAME different from c:\something? I can give standard users rights to files.

Comment: Apples and oranges.  Privileges aren't implemented in the same way access rights are, they're completely different things.

Comment: You can in fact assign arbitrary privileges to standard users (via Local Security Policy) but that doesn't affect administrators, who would still need to run the process elevated.  In your scenario, you'd need to turn UAC off.  Mind you, if you're giving standard users administrator-equivalent privileges, you've thrown out any thought of security anyway, so I guess you might as well turn UAC off too. :-)

Comment: (Note that granting [certain privileges](https://superuser.com/a/610253/96662) to a standard user will result in the the user being treated as an administrator by UAC, i.e., you will get a split token.  Rumour has it that other UAC mechanisms, such as the elevation dialog, do not behave well in this scenario.)